# React Hooks in class using timeout

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am quite new in React... I have page where window is showing with little delay..

it is made with Hooks:

```
export default function LoginPage() { 
    const [cardAnimaton, setCardAnimation] = React.useState('cardHidden');
    setTimeout(function() {
        setCardAnimation('');
  }, 700);

  <form>
  <Card login className={classes[cardAnimaton]}>
```

Now I want to use classes in that page and I want to preserve the same effect..

So I am trying something like:

```
export default class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cardHidden: true,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setCardAnimation('');
        }, 700);
    }
    setCardAnimation = () => {
        this.cardAnimaton({ cardHidden: false });
    };
```

I have no idea... got stuck there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set your `cardHidden: false` inside `componentDidMount` and then you can add animation based on `cardHidden` state.

here is a working Demo which I used `cardHidden` state to show or hide different text on screen which you can use this method for adding different animation.

just click `Run code snippet` to see how it works

```js
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cardHidden: true,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
              cardHidden: false
            });
        }, 700);
    }
    
    render() {
      if(this.state.cardHidden){
        return <div>I'm Hidden</div>
      } else {
        return <div>Haha, I'm Visible</div>
      }
    }
}

const rootDiv = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(<LoginPage />, rootDiv);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In class-based component, you need to use `this.setState` to update the state.

```
export default class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cardHidden: true,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ cardHidden: false });
        }, 700);
    }
...
```

check https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: hmm.. true, I was thinking that setCardAnimation function is doing the same thing after timeout... thanks! But how do I relate <Card login className={classes[cardAnimaton]}> now.. Thanks

Comment: hi, I don't understand your question. what do you mean by relate?

Comment: Sorry I got it, I just added if(this.state.cardHidden){... and it worked for me, thanks!